# What version of TypeScript does Angular2 require?

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript1.8, typescript2.0

What is the minimum version of TypeScript that Angular2 requires? Specifically, is TypeScript 1.8 sufficient, or do you have to have TypeScript 2.0?

We want to use TypeScript, but have a big project using 1.8 that is not completely trivial to upgrade.

Answer (score 2):

Typescript 1.8 works fine, We have been using typescript 1.8 with the final Angular 2.0 and there's no problem at all.

Would that be true for future versions? Probably not.

The Angular team is developing with typescript 2.0.2 as you can see in this [commit](https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/2b20db6c5acd60721e8a5dae2b50cdb1292f8db1) since RC5 and so far typescript 1.8 is working fine.